# How to get comments in v1.1 Twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

Is it possible to get the comments from a tweet in version 1.1 of the Twitter API?

I know it's possible in version 2.0 but I must use version 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct ability to retrieve a thread using `conversation_id` in v1.1 - this functionality does not exist. You would have to try to use the search API to find replies, but this is much more difficult and less likely to find threaded responses.

Comment: Thanks, Imagine if I found a Tweet, does the Tweet have a list of replies conversation_id in that scope, so I can search by ID or are you saying that I would have to search for all tweet with a parent ID of the current tweet?

Comment: There is no such thing as the concept of conversation ID in v1.1, so you would need to filter for Tweets that are in_reply_to the Tweet ID of the source Tweet. It's tedious in v1.1 unfortunately.